# Getting the ID of a datetime_select field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails web application in which I need to enable or disable a datetime_select field as a checkbox is checked or unchecked.  In order to do this quickly and dynamically, I need to have this done using javascript.

My problem is I can't seem to assign an ID to the datetime_select to have the javascript grab the datetime_select and enable it or disable it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Start by posting some code here. This is probably trivial, but we can't see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id using a 4th attribute of [`date_time_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select)  which is `html_options`. Here is an example:

```
datetime_select :article, :written_on, {}, :id => 'some_id'
```

However, this is not a good idea as you will end up with 5 select elements with the same id in your html. Better alternative is to wrap the datetime select in a span and set an id to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f.datetime_select "your_field", {}, {id: "your_element_id"}
```

Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-datetime_select

Interface of method datetime_select is

```
datetime_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```